# Point at which insertion sort beats quicksort

Tags: c, sorting

I'm writing a quicksort that switches to insertion sort when the length of the array being sorted is small.  I've run some tests and from what I see, when the array being sorted is 200 elements or less, it is faster to switch to insertion sort.  This seems really large, I was expecting something closer to 20. Is 200 reasonable or is one of my implementations way off? I used the basic Wikipedia algorithms.

```
void quicksort(int list[asize], int left, int right)
{
    int pivotindex;
    int newpivotindex;

    if (left < right)
    {
            if ((right-left)<=200)
            {
            insertionsort(list,left,right);
            }
    }
    else
    {
        pivotindex = r_rand(left,right);
        newpivotindex = partition(list, left, right, pivotindex);

        quicksort(list, left, newpivotindex-1);
        quicksort(list, newpivotindex+1, right); 
    }
    return;
}

int partition(int* list,int left, int right, int pivotindex)
{
int pivotvalue = list[pivotindex];
int temp;
int i;
int storeindex;

temp=list[pivotindex];
list[pivotindex]=list[right];
list[right]=temp;

storeindex=left;

for (i=left;i<right;i++)
{
    if (list[i] < pivotvalue)
    {
        temp=list[i];
        list[i]=list[storeindex];
        list[storeindex]=temp;

        storeindex++;
    }
}

temp=list[storeindex];
list[storeindex]=list[right];
list[right]=temp;

return storeindex;
}

void insertionsort(int* list, int left, int right)
{
int i;
int item;
int ihole;

for (i=left;i<=right;i++)
{
    item=list[i];
    ihole=i;
    while (ihole > 0 && list[ihole-1] > item)
    {
        list[ihole]=list[ihole-1];
        ihole--;
    }
    list[ihole]=item;
}

return;
}
```

Comment: What I heard last was ~100, so that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Does this even work?  It looks like it only ever invokes the quicksort part if `right` is less than or equal to `left`.

Comment: Off-hand, I suspect your quicksort is broken or poorly implemented. Unless you hit a worst-case by choosing bad pivots, quicksort should not be significantly worse than insertion sort...

Comment: By the way, if you want to optimize the "leaves" of a quicksort, I would use sorting networks, not insertion sort. I have a past question whose answer tabulates optimal sorting networks up to a fairly large size.

Comment: @paddy  not sure where you at seeing that.  It's actually the opposite. Left and right are the indicies that form the sub array to be sorted.if right is less that or equal to left, then the sub array has 0 or 1 elements, so it is already sorted

Comment: Yes, I know that...  My point is that your `else` is in the wrong place.  The code you have provided will either do an insertion sort or nothing at all (unless you call it with invalid parameters or an array of 1 element, in which case it will attempt quicksort).

Comment: ahh yes, the brackets got messed up when I copied the code over

Comment: So does that mean you have been testing incorrect code?  Or does the question still stand?  From memory, implementations of quicksort that I have seen tend to put the threshold at less than 10 elements.

Comment: One factor that controls when the switchover is effective is the cost of a comparison.  For integers, the comparison is very cheap; if you were sorting an array of structures which had string members, each up to 200 characters long, to be compared using `strcoll()`, then the cost of a comparison is vastly greater and it may be more effective to defer the switchover to insertion sort.